# Android Java: Using setOnClickListener in for loop

Tags: java, android, for-loop, final

I'm in the early stages of android development and I had a problem with a `for` loop.

Here is my code:

```
for (int i=0; i<=30; i++){

        tableRows[i] = new TableRow(this);
        tableRows[i].setId(i);
        tableRows[i].setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
        tableRows[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);

        textViews1[i] = new TextView(this);
        textViews1[i].setText("Eng Kelime " + i);
        textViews1[i].setTextSize(25);
        textViews1[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        textViews1[i].setId(i);
        textViews1[i].setPadding(20, 30, 0, 0);
        textViews1[i].setLayoutParams(Params2);
        tableRows[i].addView(textViews1[i]);

        textViews2[i] = new TextView(this);
        textViews2[i].setText("Tr Kelime " + i);
        textViews2[i].setTextSize(25);
        textViews2[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        textViews2[i].setId(i);
        textViews2[i].setPadding(30,30,0,0);
        textViews2[i].setLayoutParams(Params2);
        tableRows[i].addView(textViews2[i]);

        tableLayout.addView(tableRows[i]);

        textViews1[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //These textViews[i] veriables need to be declared final.  
                //But I don't know how!..

                if (textViews2[i].getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    textViews2[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }else{
                    textViews2[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

I have `TableRows` and two `textViews` in each `TableRows`. When I click the first `textView1[i]`, the second one, `textView2[i]` will be invisible or visible.

But in `setOnClickListener` code block I had *"variable 'i' is accessed from within inner class needs to be declared final" error code.*

I have declared `i` as `final`, like `for(final int i=0; i<=30; i++)`. Then I had a different error. *"Variable 'i' Can not be declared final"*

Comment: you cannot change the value of final variable.remember that

Comment: Declare i as member variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare a new variable `j` and modify your code as:

```
final int j = i;
textViews1[j].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (textViews2[j].getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                textViews2[j].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }else{
                textViews2[j].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Try this. This will work.

Comment: Thank you very much. That works. :) I can't vote your answer. I don't have Moderation Privilege. I'm sorry..

Comment: @DegetThe: can you please mark the answer as correct ? It will be useful to others. Thanks :)

Comment: I marked it as correct answer. It was green.. I checked it again. now?

Comment: OK.  I won't change. :) I still don't know how to use it. I'll learn it soon.

Answer (score 2):

In order to access a local variable from an inner class, it must be declared `final`, so it cannot be changed externally. You could do this by using an additional dummy variable:

```
final index = i; // here!
textViews1[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (textViews2[index].getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                textViews2[index].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }else{
                textViews2[index].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
final TextView txtToToggle = textViews2[i];
textViews1[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (txtToToggle.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            txtToToggle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            txtToToggle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have declered "i" as final like "for(final int i=0; i<=30; i++)". Then I had > a different error. "Veriable 'i' Can not be declared final"

Declaring *i* as final means you cannot change the value of *i*. Hence, *i++* would be invalid. You can not declare *i* as final in a *for* loop.

A way around would be to create a new variable, say *j*, as final and assign it the value of *i*. In inner class, use *j* instead of *i* as stated by @ZygoteInit.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood what does final do now.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I provide you a very simple trick to that in Java, with JMenuItem, but you can do the same for your project:

```
    package tests;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class MyMenu extends JMenuBar {

    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
    private ArrayList<JMenuItem> jMenus = new ArrayList<JMenuItem>();

    public MyMenu() {
        populateMenu();
        createMenu();
        createAction();
    }

    private void populateMenu(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            list.add("Object "+i);
        }
    }

    private void createMenu(){
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(list.get(i));
            jMenus.add(item);
            menu.add(item);
        }
        add(menu);
    }

    private void createAction(){

        for (int i = 0; i < jMenus.size(); i++) {
            final int index = i;
            jMenus.get(i).addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println(jMenus.get(index).getText());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```